# Using Count and Distinct with a Where

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to display a dropdown of distinct Brands, furthermore i'm looking to display a summary of the number of items within that match a WHERE statement. Looking around here i'm only able to find solutions to part of my problem, but not the SELECT WHERE part that needs to be nested...

Progress so far...

```
SELECT brand,COUNT(DISTINCT linked_id WHERE done=0) as count FROM products GROUP BY brand ORDER BY brand;
```

This clearly won't run, but does provide some sudo to what i'm looking to achieve.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: What's wrong with this `SELECT brand, COUNT(DISTINCT linked_id) as count FROM products  WHERE done=0 GROUP BY brand ORDER BY brand;`?

Comment: @the.salman.a That will leave out the brands where none of the rows have `done = 0`, rather than showing a count of `0` for them.

Comment: I just wanted to clear that. You've got two answers, I think those'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this?

```
SELECT 
    brand, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN done = 0 THEN linked_id ELSE NULL END) AS count 
FROM 
    products 
GROUP BY 
    brand 
ORDER BY 
    brand;
```

Edited to remove [count] and make this back to count.

Comment: Thanks for this - both great working answers, I've added in a few extra conditions and it working sweet! Thank you so much...

Answer (score 2):

You should count distinct when your filter is true.

```
SELECT
    brand,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN done = 0 THEN linked_id END)) count
FROM
    products
GROUP BY
    brand
ORDER BY
    brand
```